# Increase an array index by 1 C#

Tags: c#, arrays, counter

I have an integer array that I use for counting.

What is the easiest way to increase a certain index of the integer array by 1?

My code looks like this at the moment.

```
input = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
number1 = rand.Next(1, 7);
number2 = rand.Next(1, 7);
number3 = rand.Next(1, 7);

//array used to keep track of how many times a certain number has showed up
int[] counters = new int[14];

int sum = number1 + number2 + number3;

for (int i = 0; i <= input; i++)
{

    counters[sum] = counters[sum] + 1; //counters[sum]++;???
}

for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
{
    richTextBox1.Text += "The number " + (i + 1) + "showed up" + counters[i] + " times\n";
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I do:

```
array[i]++;    or     array[i] = array[i] + 1; ???
```

EDIT for clarity.

What i am trying to do:

roll 3 dices as often as the user wants

sum the 3 dice rolls together (sum should be between 3 -18)
and then keep a count of how often each sum showed up.

Then lastly display in % how many times each number showed up.

Comment: Is it giving you an error about uninitialized variables?

Comment: the array just shows up as zeros

Comment: `number1 + number2 + number3` could result in a number that is >= 14 and thus out of range for your array.  It's not clear what you are attempting to achieve with this code.

Comment: Apart from the problem of the out of range what is the purpose of your first loop. Just write _counters[sum] += input+1_

Comment: You do realise that this code will only update a single element of the array?

Comment: @Onyth I still doesnt understand what you want to do, but there is somethig weird in this code, in first loop, you always change the same position on array. The sum variable, can be greater than length of array, and it will breack in runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you actually want is the following.

```
Random rand = new Random();
int numberOfRolls = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
int[] counters = new int[16]; //16 different possible sums (3 to 18)

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRolls; i++)
{
    int sum = rand.Next(1, 7) + rand.Next(1, 7) + rand.Next(1, 7);
    counters[sum - 3]++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    richTextBox1.Text += "The number " + (i + 3) + " showed up " + counters[i] + " times\n";
}
```

This take the number of times to roll from `textBox1` then loops that number of times creating a `sum` from the 3 random numbers (1-6).  And increments a corresponding position in the array.  Since there are 16 possibilities the array is initialed to that size and you just subtract 3 to convert from the sum to the index and then add 3 to convert back when printing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq and List to do this, see this code:

```
input = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

for(var i = 0; i < input; i++)
{
    number1 = rand.Next(1, 7);
    number2 = rand.Next(1, 7);
    number3 = rand.Next(1, 7);

    //array used to keep track of how many times a certain number has showed up
    int sum = number1 + number2 + number3;
    sums.Add(sum); //Where sums is a List<int>
}
var report = sums.GroupBy(i => i).Select(g => new { TimesShowedUp = g.Count(), Sum = g.Key });

foreach(var r in report)
{
    richTextBox1.Text += "The number " + r.Sum + "showed up" + r.TimesShowedUp + " times\n";
}
```

Comment: Your code isn't even using the `input` that determines how many times the dice are suppose to be rolled.

Comment: @juharr I just changed to use input

Answer (score 0):

```
//array used to keep track of how many times a certain number has showed up
int[] counters = new int[15];

iterations = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

for (int i = 1; i <= iterations; i++)
{
    number1 = rand.Next(1, 7);
    number2 = rand.Next(1, 7);
    number3 = rand.Next(1, 7);

    int sum = number1 + number2 + number3;

    counters[sum-3]++;
}

for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
{
    richTextBox1.Text += "The number " + (i + 3) + " showed up " + counters[i] + " times\n";
}
```